# How to add a appsettings.json in a console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application, visual-studio-2019

In want to add an appsettings.JSON file to my console application project.
When I want to add a new file the appsettings.JSON template file doesn't appear.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can add a appsettings.JSON file to my console application?

Comment: Just add a file named appsettings.json.

Comment: You can look at Worker template with IHost for example and add application json as a dependency injection. I think it is a good alternative way of using console app aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Add it manually in root folder (appSettings.json) and include to your project.